# "fftw.h not found" after installing it in Mac terminal

Tags: signal-processing, fft, fftw

I'm running problem of getting fftw working. I'm on mac and have installed fftw using brew on the terminal.

```
brew install fftw
```

It gave me a reminder of "Warning: fftw 3.3.8 is already installed and up-to-date" if I put in this install command again. But I cannot call fftw.h in C. It gave me an error of "fftw.h file not found" if I have a line of

```
#include <fftw.h>
```

I also tried installing directly by

```
./configure
make
make install
```

and ran

```
make check
```

It told me "FFTW transforms passed basic tests!", but it still didn't work in C.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Please share your compile command. Typically you’d have to pass the location of the FFTW header files to the compiler, and the location of the library to the linker.

Comment: It should be `<fftw3.h>`, not `<fftw.h>`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks for your reply. Yes I did enter the directory "fftw-3.3.8" before I put the install command.

Comment: @PaulR Thanks for pointing that out, but it was a typo and it still didn't work after I made the change.

Comment: Not in the *install* command, but in the *compile* command. When you compile your own C file you need to give the directory where the FFTW include files are located.

Comment: Please show *how* you compile your own C file. This is the one that gives you an error message. If you don’t show what you did before you got the error message, we can’t tell you what the problem is.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks! It was actually because I ran the C code in XCode. It worked after I complied it in terminal.

Comment: You should be able to set up your project in XCode to find these headers too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the location of the header to your compiler. Adding the directory inclusion for either installation in both cases the header can be found in `/usr/local/include`

```
gcc ... -I/usr/local/include ...
```

Additionally, as has been pointed out, you need to `#include <fftw3.h>`. Also be reminded, that your `autoconf` build only has the double precision functionality installed. While the `brew` installation brings all 3 precisions, `float`, `double` and `long double`.

You will hit a wall again, possibly, when you want to link. Add `-L/usr/local/lib` to the linker command to be able to link like so `-lfftw3 -lfftw3f -lfftw3l` etc